# Redux/React-Redux - using "state = XXX" in the reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

We're using Redux.js with React.js (React-Redux), and in the reducer we're using the following code (we are using redux-actions to reduce boilerplate):

```
const update = require('react/lib/update');
const myReducer = handleActions
({
     [myAction]: (state, action) => {
         state = update(state, {
             something: {$set: !state.someProperty}
         });
         return someFunction(state);
     }
})
```

We are using `update` from [React Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) but assigning the result into the state using `state =`.

Is this against the [basic Redux guidlines](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) - i.e. mutating the state? It seems so, but the code seems to work perfectly and quickly, and the redux devtools shows the state changes correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example *is* okay, because you're not actually mutating the contents of the object that the `state` variable points to.  Instead, you're just updating the local variable named `state` to point to a different object instead.

It's important to understand how variables and references work in Javascript, which will help clear up what's going on here.

Personally, I'd suggest doing `const newState = update(....)` for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it! I was confused, because when changing the **contents** of the local variable `state` (by using `push` or setting a property or whatever), you **are** changing the actual state object. But by changing the reference to something else, JS doesn't change the original object, but changes the reference of the local variable. Good :-)